# Unable to connect ubuntu linux on windows putty

Tags: server

I am unable to connect to ubuntu linux on windows putty machine.I have taken ip from ifconfig and I am trying to login via putty using the same ip.I am getting network refused warning.Can anyone please help me how to resolve the issue.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for the help  sudo apt install openssh-server worked for me

Comment: I am facing one more problem while I am connecting to ubuntu linux on my putty while I am on ethernet(LAN).Can anyone please help me here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the `openssh-server` package on Ubuntu :

```
sudo tasksel install openssh-server
```

Or:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

Check the status of the service :

```
sudo systemctl status ssh.service
```

or

```
sudo service ssh status
```

or

```
sudo systemctl status sshd.service
```

To start the service just replace `status` with `start` on the above commands

Allowing the `port 22` through `ufw`:

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

Comment: Why use `tasksel` and not `apt` ?

Comment: @N.Cornet All roads lead to Rome. i will edit with `apt`.